# Declaring generic functions using callable interfaces in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to define typings for [`lodash/fp`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) and its curried and overloaded functions. In order to keep it succinct and readable, I was attempting to define a few interfaces that would do all the currying combinations automatically, like this:

```
interface Curry1<A, Z> {
  (arg1: A): Z;
}

interface Curry2<A, B, Z> {
  (arg1: A): Curry1<B, Z>;
  (arg1: A, arg2: B): Z;
}

interface Curry3 { ... }
```

Using `map` as the test case, I want to define a function along these lines:

```
const map<T, U>: Curry2<(arg: T) => U, T[], U[]>;
```

But this is no good; you can't use generics in a variable declaration like this. I have also tried faking it using classes (which allow generics in this manner, but are not callable as functions) and namespaces (which don't seem to change anything at all, they just add more braces to the code).

Am I doomed to just redeclare a bunch of `function` overrides like this?

```
function map<T, U>(iteratee: (arg: T) => U): (data: T[]) => U[];
function map<T, U>(iteratee: (arg: T) => U, data: T[]): U[];

// This is equivalent to:

function map<T, U>(iteratee: (arg: T) => U): Curry1<T[], U[]>;
function map<T, U>(iteratee: (arg: T) => U, data: T[]): U[];
```

That last pair of overrides is just an inlined definition for `Curry2`, and it quickly gets obnoxious (especially when you get to `Curry3` and `Curry4`), in addition to just being pointless grunt to write/generate.

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably need to declare each override signature.

Comment: I was hoping there was some nonobvious syntax like `
function map<T, U>: Curry2<(arg: T) => U, T[], U[]>;`, but admittedly this is a somewhat weird and very narrow use-case.